# Redirect causing a redirect loop

Tags: php, redirect

I used the following code in my Function.php file to redirect users who are not logged-in to the 'my-account' page where they are promoted to sign up or log in.

```
if (
  !in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php', '/my-account'))
  && !is_admin()
  && !is_user_logged_in()
) {
  wp_redirect('/my-account', 301);
  exit;
}
```

However the code causes a redirect loop on the 'my-account' page and I can't seem to work out why.  Newish to PHP, thanks for any help!

*edit: amended /my-account typo*

Comment: I think the main thing may be that `/my-account` !== `/my-account/`. Another thing I'm not sure about is why your condition redirects users to their account when they're _not_ logged in?

Comment: Apologies the /my-account and /my-account/ is a typo that I was meant to amend before posting. And the account page acts as a login/register form when the user isn't logged in

Comment: Okay, I guess the next question is where are you setting `pagenow` and what is the actual value when you hit `/my-account`.

Comment: I assumed the array was setting the pagenow but honestly I have no idea. And also not sure what you mean by value. PHP beginner issues.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise `pagenow` was a WP thing, So if you add `var_dump($GLOBALS['pagenow']); exit;` just before the `wp_redirect` when you hit `/my-account` URL, what does it output?

Comment: No redirect error this time but getting ' string(9) "index.php" ' outputted on a blank page

Comment: So it looks like you actually want to be using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of the globals superglobal to check the URL. WP might have its own variable for this, but I don't know.

Comment: Getting a similar output but now its ' string(11) "/my-account" '  EDIT: after clearing cash the output changed to ' string(1) "/" ' EDIT: it seems to be outputting the page id (possibly?) it changes for each page

Comment: Maybe `my-account` page is redirects user backward to page with your function. And it repeats again and again

Comment: Inspect element shows that the account page is the only one being accessed